# permission denied fopen while gzipping

Tags: php, gzip

I am trying to zip all xml files in a current diretory and then moving all these zipped files from directory to another.However i always receive  "fopen(.): failed to open stream: Permission denied" error. Here is my   code for gzip;

```
$dest = 'test2.gz'; 
$mode = 'wb' . $level; 
$error = false; 
if ($fp_out = gzopen($dest, $mode)) { 
    if ($fp_in = fopen($merged,'rb')) { 
        while (!feof($fp_in)) 
            gzwrite($fp_out, fread($fp_in, 1024 * 512)); 
        fclose($fp_in); 
    } else {
        $error = true; 
    }
    gzclose($fp_out); 
} else {
    $error = true; 
}
if ($error)
    return false; 
else
    return $dest;

 }
$files = scandir("export");
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
  gzCompressFile($file_name);}
```

Comment: What are the file permissions on the target file(s)? Are you running this script as root?

Comment: please forgive my lack of knowledge , i am beginner and i am using  laravel framework  and this function runs on one of my methods  in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change the permission of the file by chmod command from shell

```
sudo chmod 777 filename
```

or you can alternatively run the process as a root user.